# SQL Bulk Insert in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, csv, pyodbc, bulkinsert

I have a Python script that imports Excel data, formats a few columns/rows and saves the result as a CSV. This CSV is then moved to a server directory (via the script) so that I can run a SQL Bulk INSERT query to populate it's contents into a SQL Table.
However, my script appends the current date to the filename when saving the CSV. How can I edit the Bulk INSERT part of my code to ensure it captures this filename every time the script is run, so that I don't have to manually edit the SQL part? I know I could leave the appending part out but I need this for audit purposes.

Here is the relevant part of my script (SQL part with *** indicates where I'd want the new name to be automatically captured (e.g. testdata_15092020.csv)):

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import shutil
import glob
import pyodbc

os.system("cls")

# ...Multiple formatting steps...

currenttime = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime('%d%m%Y')
join.to_csv("testdata_" + currenttime + ".csv", index=False)

for CSVfile in glob.iglob(os.path.join('CURRENT WORKING DIRECTORY', "*.csv")):
    shutil.copy(CSVfile, 'SQL SERVER FILE DIRECTORY')

# ...Connection to SQL Database section...

cursor.execute("""BULK INSERT testdb.dbo.scriptresults
               FROM '\\\SERVERNAME\\TESTFILES\\***.csv' 
               WITH
               (
                 FIRSTROW = 2,
                 FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
                 ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
                 );""")
cnxn.commit()
```

Comment: Question: Why are you inserting the data into the `master` database? `master` should never be used for user objects unless you plan to make them system objects.

Comment: just using it as an example, I will be using an alternative database. Editing original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
file_name = "testdata_" + currenttime + ".csv"

cursor.execute("""BULK INSERT master.dbo.scriptresults
               FROM '\\\SERVERNAME\\TESTFILES\\""" + file_name + """' 
               WITH
               (
                 FIRSTROW = 2,
                 FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
                 ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
                 );""")
```

Comment: Thanks Jurez that worked after playing with my .to_csv part!